# Populating A Select List Dynamically MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to create a cascading dropdown. My Controller looks like this to initialize the view..

```
  public ActionResult Create()
        {

            var model = new RoundDetailViewModel();


                model.AvailableFacilities = new SelectList(db.Facilities, "FacilityId", "Facility_Name");
                model.AvailableCourses = new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<Course>(), "CourseId", "Course_Name");
                model.AvailableTeeTypes= new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<TeeType>(), "TeeTypeId", "Name");


            return View(model);
        }
```

This will populate the first dropdown, and also create 2 empty dropdown as expected.

Now on a selection of the first dropdown I want to call an Action in my controller to populate the second dropdown. This is where I am a little foggy on the code in the action to populate the second dropdown. I want to use something like this to trigger calling the action..

```
 $("#ddlFacility").change(function () {
        var selectedFacility = $(this).val();
        if (selectedFacility != null && selectedFacility != '') {
            $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetCourse")", { facility: selectedFacility }, function (courses) {
                var coursesSelect = $('#ddlCourse');
                coursesSelect.empty();
                $.each(courses, function (index, course) {
                    coursesSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                        value: course.value,
                        text: course.text
                    }));
                });
            });
        }
    });


   public ActionResult Courses(int facilityId)
        {
           //WHAT GOES HERE TO POPULATE SELECT LIST??           

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to return JsonResult and allow Get (if that is what you decide to do) Alternatively you need to make it a POST and do a POST to it.

Something like

```
public JsonResult GetCourses(int id)
{        
    var Courses= db.Courses.Where(a=>facilityId==id).ToList();
    SelectList list = new SelectList(Courses,"Text", "Value");
    return Json(list , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Is it good practice to put both if these methods in my controller? Or should the private method be put somewhere else..Just tryin to learn good practice when working with mvc?

Comment: I just pasted a cut and paste sample. If it was me. I'd just make it all part of the Action. You could also look at having a select list service that you use to return these things. If you are doing it often. Alternatively you could look at WebAPI which returns Json. We use WebAPI for all our Json stuff

Comment: Can you point me to the example where you got this. I am hitting the controller but when I get back to the javascript the JSON being returned is not formatted correctly to populate the select list. Its returning this as the Name ""System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Course_C81CDD1DDC4D486F471F64D1F95990CD3518507F0B5BB9F718C0910A56B73D12"" and the Value=null for each course. The data coming out of the controller is fine and queried correctly so ther eis something wrong with my javascript code

Comment: Updated. Where the Text and Value are enter the name of the property you want to use for the Text and Value e.g. "Name", "CourseId"